# Combine route parameters and Uri parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to combine route parameters and uri paramters. I have tried

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CqsAPi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{type}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And controller

```
public class CqsController : ApiController
{
    public object Get(string type, [FromUri] Data data)
    {
        var dto = var ParseDto<Query>(type, data);
        return _invoke.Query(dto);
    }
}
```

But I get

> No action was found on the controller 'Cqs' that matches the request.

@Patrick Hofman
Like this? Get same error

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CqsAPi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{type}/{data}"
);
```

THis works

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CqsAPi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{type}/{data}",
    defaults: new { type = RouteParameter.Optional, data = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Bummer** it didnt work, this is what I wanna do.

Url
/api/cqs/FooQuery/?id=1

Action method now looks like this

```
public object Get(string type, [FromUri] JObject data)
{
    var t = typeof(Query).Assembly.GetType(type);
    var query = data.ToObject(t) as Query;

    return _invoker.Invoke(query);
}
```

FooQuery

```
public class FooQuery : Query<IEnumerable<Foo>>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Problem now is that Id is not set

Comment: Why not add `data` to your route and remove `id`, since that isn't used?

Comment: Could you please provide url of the request and also Data class definition?

Comment: This did the trick defaults: new { type = RouteParameter.Optional, data = RouteParameter.Optional }

Comment: In reality Data is of type JObject